# No postback on any button click on ASP.NET 4.0 application

Tags: asp.net, iis

The weird thing is If there is a javascript onClick() on a button, postback works otherwise, there is no postback. This was working very recently. I am not sure what recent changes made to the application made this happening throughout the site. The solution suggested by this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889877) does not work as well (that link is applicable to .NET 1.1 though). Any idea whats going on?

**EDIT:-**

No postback when I have a button like this:-

```
<asp:button id="btnClick" runat="server" onClick="Click"/>
```

Postbacks when I have a button like this and I see the Click event handler code getting executed:-

```
<asp:button id="btnClick" runat="server" onClientClick="return Test();" onClick="Click"//>
```

and the corersponding JS function which would just return true at the end:-

```
function Test()
{
return true;
}
```

Comment: Have you isolated the problem to a simple ASPX page (no code behind) which can easily be reproduced?

Comment: Darin, I did test for a simple page and Its working..there are some master pages involved. Checking those...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any validation on your site? Could be that if the validation don't pass.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the button is not wired up to some client side event handler? Could some client side validation script be firing?